# Howto prevent XStream from displaying class="string"?

Tags: java, xml, xstream

Is there a way to prevent XStream from displaying something like follows:

```
<user class="string">user</user>
<password class="string">password</password>
```

in an xml output?

Comment: Do you want to prevent XStream to serialize some fields?

Comment: What do you mean be clean?, what is not clean in the posted example?

Comment: I want it to look like <user>user</user><password>password</password>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Omitted Fields
>
> For a proper deserialization XStream
>   has to write the complete object graph
>   into XML that is referenced by a
>   single object. Therefore XStream has
>   to find a representation that contains
>   all aspects to recreate the objects.
>
> However, some parts might be
>   superfluous e.g. if a member field is
>   lazy initialized and its content can
>   be easily recreated. In such a case a
>   field can be omitted using
>   [XStream.omitField(Class, String)](http://x-stream.github.io/javadoc/com/thoughtworks/xstream/XStream.html).

@See: [xStream Documentation](http://x-stream.github.io/manual-tweaking-output.html)

Comment: Thanx, how dumb of me though.

Comment: Ok, so here's the thing, I'm using all this from a groovy script. So *def* gives such an output. It's only a matter of field definition. But your answer was very help full.